# How to ensure this constraint at compile time?

Tags: functional-programming, swift-language, invariants

I have an interesting constraint/invariant and I would love to hear people's input on how to maintain it. Big bonus if it can be ensured at compile time...

I have the types below, and the following conceptual invariant... If an attribute's id equals an attributeValue's id, then they must have corresponding types. How would you express this invariant and ensure it is true in code?  (The code is Swift, but the question is generic. For those that don't know Swift, these are all immutable value types. They can be used just like integers or immutable strings in other languages.)

```
struct Attribute {
    let attributeID: Int
    let name: String
    let display: Bool
    let type: AttributeType
}

enum AttributeType {
    case Text
    case SingleList([AttributeChoice])
    case MultiList([AttributeChoice])
    case Date
    case Time
    case DateTime
    case Image
    case Flag
    case Count
}

struct AttributeValue {
    let attributeID: Int
    let value: AttributeValueType
}

enum AttributeValueType {
    case Text(String)
    case SingleList(AttributeChoice)
    case MultiList([AttributeChoice])
    case Date(NSDate)
    case Time(NSDate)
    case DateTime(NSDate)
    case Image(UIImage)
    case Flag(Bool)
    case Count(Int)
}

struct AttributeChoice {
    let serverID: Int
    let name: String
}
```

As I am writing this question, I was thinking that maybe the Attribute class should manage the creation of AttributeValues somehow, any other ideas?

Comment: Is there any reason `AttributeValue` has an `AttributeID` rather than an `Attribute` other than "that's how the DB stores them"?

Comment: Yes, I communicate with the back-end by ID number, but I think that I should have some more obvious way of linking them than simply "same ID number" so if you have any ideas, I would love to hear them.

Comment: Well, at least in some languages, you can make an `Attribute<T>` which then can be required to have the same `T` as `AttributeValue<T>`.

Comment: The problem is that `Attribute` and `AttributeValue` don't have identical types, they have corresponding types.

Comment: Ah, I see. Interesting.

Comment: I had the idea to use just one of the Attribute enums and mimic the two variants by using according functions inside. Just an idea...